# Numbering subsections, manually set letters or numbers

Tags: sectioning, counters, subsection

I would like to manually set subsections as letter or numbers in the same document

```
    1. First section 
        1.P. First subsection 
             1.P.1. First subsubsection
             1.P.2. Second subsubsection
        1.V. Second subsection 
    2. Second section
       2.1 First subsection
```

(Spacing not needed)

I would still like the numbering on section og subsubsection level to follow the usual counting rules.

Is it possible to do something like:

```
    \section{First section}
    \lettersubsection[P]{First subsection}
    \subsubsection{First subsubsection} 
    \subsubsection{Second subsubsection} 
    \lettersubsection[V]{Second subsection}
    \section{First section}
    \subsection{First subsection}
```

But how to define `\lettersubsection[]{}`? Here I'm stuck. Is it even possible to combine counters like that? I think I can avoid mixing letters and numbers within the same section, if that can make things easier. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might extend the `\subsection` command to take an optional argument in parentheses; in this case, the argument will be used instead of the number.

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewCommandCopy{\originalsubsection}{\subsection}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\subsection}{sd()O{#4}m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\originalsubsection*{#4}}%
    {%
     \IfNoValueTF{#2}
       {% no letter
        \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}%
       }
       {% letter
        \addtocounter{subsection}{-1}%
        \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.#2}%
       }
     \originalsubsection[#3]{#4}%
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\subsection(P){First subsection}

\subsubsection{First subsubsection}

\subsubsection{Second subsubsection} 

\subsection(V){Second subsection}\label{v}

\subsubsection{First subsubsection}\label{1-v}

\section{First section}

\subsection{First subsection}

\ref{v} and \ref{1-v}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In order for `hyperref` to work, add also

```
\renewcommand{\theHsubsection}{\thesubsection}
```

at the end of the given code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is very good, but unfortunately I get this strange error message: 
```Undefined control sequence. \NewCommandCopy```
I'm doing something very wrong, aren't I?

Comment: Based on that error, the only thing you might be doing wrong is using an older version of LaTex. If you use `xparse`, it will probably work. Can @egreg (or someone else) please confirm if that is the case?

Comment: @nunatak In that case you're running an older version of LaTeX. In order to solve the problem do instead `\usepackage{letltxmacro}` and `\LetLtxMacro{\originalsubsection}{\subsection}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I upgraded my LeTeX-version and it works! It seems however that I got an issue with table of contents (I'll make a post below):

Comment: I needed to make a new post: 
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/617880/table-of-contents-with-manipulated-subsections

Comment: @nunatak Sorry, there was a typo: one `#3` needed to be `#4`, see fix

Comment: @greg no worries at all, thanks a lot!