# Table of contents with manipulated subsections

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, subsection

I got a brilliant solution to a question on how to manipulate the subsection to also be given by letters:

[Numbering subsections, manually set letters or numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/617723/numbering-subsections-manually-set-letters-or-numbers)

But, unfortunately I got an issue with the table of contents

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

%\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\NewCommandCopy{\originalsubsection}{\subsection} %\LetLtxMacro{\originalsubsection}{\subsection} \RenewDocumentCommand{\subsection}{sd()O{#3}m}{%   \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\originalsubsection*{#4}}%
    {%
     \IfNoValueTF{#2}
       {% no letter
        \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}%
       }
       {% letter
        \addtocounter{subsection}{-1}%
        \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.#2}%
       }
     \originalsubsection[#3]{#4}%
    }% }

\renewcommand{\theHsubsection}{\thesubsection}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{First section}

\subsection(P){First subsection}

\subsubsection{First subsubsection}

\subsubsection{Second subsubsection} 

\subsection(V){Second subsection}\label{v}

\subsubsection{First subsubsection}\label{1-v}

\section{First section}

\subsection{First subsection}

\ref{v} and \ref{1-v}

\end{document}
```

The table of content looks like this:

[image]

Where `NoValue` is shown in the subsections with letters.

Any idea how to fix this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third argument in the newly-defined `\subsection` should not use `O{#3}`, but instead `o` and then test whether `#3` exists or not (using `\IfValueTF{#3}{<true>}{<false>}`). Here the `<true>` branch (if `#3` was supplied) would use it as-is, otherwise (if `#3`) was not supplied) it should use `#4`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\NewCommandCopy{\originalsubsection}{\subsection} %\LetLtxMacro{\originalsubsection}{\subsection}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\subsection}{s d() o m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\originalsubsection*{#4}}%
    {%
     \IfValueTF{#2}
       {% letter
        \addtocounter{subsection}{-1}%
        \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.#2}%
       }
       {% no letter
        \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}%
       }%
     \originalsubsection[\IfValueTF{#3}{#3}{#4}]{#4}%
    }%
}

\renewcommand{\theHsubsection}{\thesubsection}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{First section}

\subsection(P){First subsection}

\subsubsection{First subsubsection}

\subsubsection{Second subsubsection} 

\subsection(V){Second subsection}\label{v}

\subsubsection{First subsubsection}\label{1-v}

\section{First section}

\subsection{First subsection}

\ref{v} and \ref{1-v}

\end{document}
```

Comment: great, thanks a lot!